# Feathers unique client id?

Tags: feathersjs

I am running a feathers.js application and I am watching for updates on a resource. I want to be able to uniquely identify if I am the client that sent the update. What is the best way to tell that?

If I am logged on as the same user on 2 identical browser windows, I should also be able to tell if I updated the resource from my current browser window.

EDIT: Or is there a way to at least stop sending the update to the client that made it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took some digging, but I was able to get this working pretty well with some [custom express middleware](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/socketio.html#params).

```js
// app.js

app.configure(
  socketio(io => {
    io.use((socket, next) => {
      socket.feathers.connectionID = socket.client.id;
      next();
    });
  })
);
```

```js
// myService.service.js (or wherever you set up your channels)

service.publish((data, context) => {
  return app.channel(...).filter((connection) => {
    const senderConnectionID = context.params.connection.connectionID;
    const thisConnectionID = connection.connectionID;
    return senderConnectionID !== thisConnectionID;
  });
});
```

It doesn't require any client-side setup, but in my case I'm using this to identify sessions, so I did make sure I was only creating one socket per page load and sharing it between all my client instances.